# digital clock am/pm display problems/ EDIT: here is the whole thing

Tags: c

`#include<conio.h>`
`#include<process.h>`
`#include<stdio.h>`
`#include<windows.h>`

`int sun()`
`void gotoxy(int x, int y);`
`int EV(int i,int x,int y);`
`int h,m,s;`
`char ch='p';`
`void Z (int x,int y);`
`void O (int x,int y);`
`void T (int x,int y);`
`void TE (int x,int y);`
`void F (int x,int y);`
`void FE (int x,int y);`
`void S (int x,int y);`
`void SN (int x,int y);`
`void E (int x,int y);`
`void N (int x, int y);`
`void TN (int x,int y);`
`void AA (int x,int y);`
`void PP (int x,int y);`
`void MM (int x,int y);`
`void CC (int x,int y);`

`main()`
`{`
      `int set;`
`void watch();`
`void main_menu();`

`main_menu();`
`watch();`

`while(1)`
`{`
`if(kbhit())`
`ch=getch();`
`if(ch=='s'||ch=='S')`
`break;`
`if(ch=='e'||ch=='E')`
`exit(0);`
`}`

`while(1)`
`{`
`watch();`
`sleep(1000);`
`if(kbhit())`
`ch=getch();`

`if(ch=='r'||ch=='R')`
`{`
`main_menu();`
`watch();`

`while(1)`
`{`
`if(kbhit())`
`ch=getch();`
`if(ch=='s'||ch=='S')`
`break;`
`if(ch=='e'||ch=='E')`
`exit(0);`
`}`
`}`
`else`
`if(ch=='p'||ch=='P')`
`while(1)`
`{`
if(kbhit())
ch=getch();
if(ch=='s'||ch=='S')
break;
if(ch=='e'||ch=='E')
exit(0);
if(ch=='r'||ch=='R')
{
ch='c';
main_menu();
watch();
}
}
else
if(ch=='e'||ch=='E')
exit(0);`

`if(s!=59)`
`s++;`
`else`
`{`
`s=0;`
`if(m!=59)`
`m++;`
`else`
`{`
`m=0;`
`if(h!=12)`
`h++;`
`else`
`{`
`h=1;`
`}`
`}`
`}`
`}`
`}`

`void watch()`
`{`
    `int ampm,AP,OS,TS,x,y;`

```
` if (ampm!=112)`
` {`
` AP = 97;`
    }`
```

`else`
  `{`
       `AP=112;`
       `}`

`system("cls");`

```
            `TS = h/10;`
           ` OS = h%10;`
           ` x =12;`
          `  y = 5;`
  `EV(TS,x,y);`
  `x+=6;`
 ` EV(OS,x,y);`
 ` x+=6;`
 ` CC(x,y);`
 ` TS = m/10;`
 ` OS = m%10;`
 ` x+=5;`
  `EV(TS,x,y);`
  `x+=6;`
 ` EV(OS,x,y);`
 ` x+=6;`
 ` CC(x,y);`
 ` TS = s/10;`
 ` OS = s%10;`
  `x+=5;`
 ` EV(TS,x,y);`
  `x+=6;`
 ` EV(OS,x,y);`
  `x+=6; `

 `  if (h==12)`
```

`{`
 if (AP==112)
 AP=97;`

```
     ` else if (AP==97)`
          ` AP=112;`
         `  }   `
```

`if (AP==97)`
   `AA(x,y);`
 `else if (AP==112)`
    `PP(x,y);` 
x+=5;
 MM(x,y);`

`printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPress Key");`
`printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t---------");`
`printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\ts -> Start");`
`printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tp -> Pause");`
`printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tr -> Reset");`
`printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\te -> Exit");`

`}`
void main_menu()
{
    `int ampm;`
     `system("cls");`
    `printf("WELCOME TO THE TIME MACHINE!!");`
    `printf("\nPlease input the desired time you want to travel to:");`
     `printf("\nHour:");`
     `scanf("%d",&h);`
    `printf("\nMinute:");`
     `scanf("%d",&m);`
    `printf("\nSecond:");`
    `scanf("%d",&s);`
    `ampm=sun();`
   `system("cls");`
   `}`
`void Z (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" ***");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   *");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("*   *");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*   *");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" ***");`
`}`

`void O (int x,int y)`
`{`
    `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("***  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("  *  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("  *  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("  *  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("*****\n");`
`}`

`void T (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("*****  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("    * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*       \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("*****  \n");`
`}`

`void TE (int x,int y)`
`{`
    `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("*****  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("    * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("  *** \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("    * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("***** \n");`
`}`

`void F (int x,int y)`
`{`
    `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("    * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("    * \n");`
`}

`void FE (int x,int y)`
{
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("*****  \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*    \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("*****  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("    * \n");`
   `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("*****  \n");`
`}`

`void S (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" ***  \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*     \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" ***  \n");`
`}`

`void SN (int x, int y)`
`{`
    `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("***** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("    * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("   * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("  * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" *  \n");`
`}`

`void E (int x,int y)`
`{`
    `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" ***  \n");`
   `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" ***  \n");`
`}`

`void N (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" ***  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("    * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" ***  \n");`
`}`

`void AA (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" ***  \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("*   * \n");`
`}`

`void PP (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf("***** \n");`
   `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf("*   * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf("***** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf("*     \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf("*     \n");`
`}`

`void MM (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" *   * \n");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf(" ** ** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf(" * * * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf(" *   * \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" *   * \n");`
`}`

`void CC (int x,int y)`
`{`
     `gotoxy(x,y)  ;printf(" \n ");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+1);printf(" ** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+2);printf(" \n ");`
     `gotoxy(x,y+3);printf(" ** \n");`
    `gotoxy(x,y+4);printf(" \n ");`
`}`
`int EV(int i,int x,int y)`
`{`
 `switch(i)`
 `{`
        `case 0:`
               `{`
                     `Z(x,y); break;}`
          `case 1:`
              `{`
                       `O(x,y); break;}`
         `case 2:`
              `{`
                       `T(x,y); break;}`
         `case 3:`
              `{`
                      `TE(x,y); break;}`
         `case 4:`
              `{`
                    `F(x,y); break;}`
          `case 5:`
              `{`
                      `FE(x,y); break;}`
          `case 6:`
               `{`
                      `S(x,y); break;}`
          `case 7:`
               `{`
                      `SN(x,y); break;}`
          `case 8:`
               `{`
                      `E(x,y); break;}`
          `case 9:`
              `{`
                      `N(x,y); break;}`
`}`
`}`
`void gotoxy(int x, int y)`
`{`
    `COORD coord;`
     `coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;`
     `SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);`
`}`
`int sun()`
`{`
 `int key,ampm;`
       `gotoxy(23,14);printf("\n Press A for AM");`
       `gotoxy(27,15);printf("\n Press P for PM");`
       `if(kbhit())`
                  `if(key=getch()=='a')ampm = 97;`
                 `if(key=getch()=='p')ampm = 112;`
                `return ampm;`
                  `}`

when I input the time to be 11:59:59AM it will display properly and will go 12:00:00PM when I would start the clock. but when I input 11:59:59PM only M would display and when start the clock it will display 11:59:59AM and will go to PM.
sorry new to programming.

Comment: What's with the macros? What do they do? What are the values of the global variables? What result would you expect? What is the actual result? Have you tried stepping through the function line by line in a debugger?

Comment: But most importantly, you don't initialize `set` anywhere, so its value is *indeterminate* and using it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). And do you initialize all other local variables before you use them?

Comment: FIX YOUR FORMATTING! It hurts in the eyes. (And probably hides your bug)

Comment: And use *proper naming*, something which tells what the variables, functions and macros are for or how they are used.

Comment: The impenetrable macro names and magic numbers make this code impossible to read.

Comment: That is a giant pile of unmaintainability.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following.

If your set variable contains anything but 112 then your AP is set to 97 and properly handled as AM formatted.

But!

Even if your set is equals 112, you do not set your AP variable to 112.

A simple modification in the code would solve your problem:

```
if (set!=112)
{
 AP = 97;
 }
else
{
  AP = 112;
}
```

This way, you will set your AP to 112 and properly write P before you write M.

Comment: Also, i have to add, that your code naming is realy hard to read. Try to use  tabbing, formatting and proper naming. Also, you should share the additional methods as well.